# Can't use values returned from Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using the multiprocessing technique in a method within a class (the class will eventually be imported into the main class to be executed), and the code segment is the following

```
        result = []
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
            data = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
            result_m = [pool.starmap(some_function, data)]
            pool.join()
            pool.close()
            result.append(result_m[0])
            result.append(result_m[1])
            result.append(result_m[2])
            result.append(result_m[3])
        first = result[0]
        sceond = result[1]
        third = result[2]
        fourth = result[3]
```

Basically, the idea is to use multiprocessing to call another method named some_function() simultaneously in four processes, and then append the result from each process to a list named "result". However, when I run the code, it always says "list index out of range" for the last four lines. It seems that the results never got added to the list defined earlier. I am wondering why this is the case and what are some potential ways to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `if` block isn't being entered. Why is it even there?

Comment: Any code outside of the required `if __name__ == '__main__':` block may get executed in *each* process - which would be disastrous in your case, since `result` only exists in the main process.

Comment: Indentation isn't clear here. Is this code running at module level (Its full left in the script)? It could be that these lines are running in the subprocess because they are not in `if __name__ == '__main__':`. This would be more clear if you posted the actual error traceback message.

Comment: @tazman - that's the normal to protect module level code in a script using multiprocessing on Windows.

Comment: @tzaman the block is there because I need to use multiprocessing. I am developing the code using PyCharm on Windows and it seems that without the block, the multiprocessing code cannot run properly.

Comment: @johz - You are correct, its needed on windows. But the bad code seems not to be in that `if`.

Comment: @tdelaney no it's not running at module level. It's within a method in a class. And this class is imported to another class to get executed. But now it seems that the loop is not even entered when running this class from main()

Comment: @johz - Lets focus on the top level script - the .py you execute - for a moment. That's the thing that is called `"__main__"` when executed, but some other name when reimported by multiprocessing. That's where you make sure that no script level code that you don't want executed on import is placed in the `if`. That's the code you need to make import safe. If something at script level eventually gets to the code you show here, you get the error in the child processes.

Comment: If that code is not in your top level script, there's your problem. Only that one script is named `"__main__"`. If its in any other module, the `if` will not run and the list will not be built.